# Issue using "column-count" on Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I was over this problem last 2 hours and I don't figuire it out of how could I fix this.

I am using `column-count` and `column-width`css property to create a nice and stable mosaic in HTML5.

**Here's my code** <-- Note that I need to put absolute value in `-webkit-column-width` property, the `%` didn't work.

```
<aside class="lastarticles">
    <div class="article">
      <div class="thumb"><img class="transition" src="media/thumb/thumb1.jpg">
        <div class="hoverarticle transition">
          <a href="single.html"><div class="readmore">
            <div class="midler"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </div>
          </div></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>“Como é que vocês se conheceram?”
          "Mas nós não nos conhecemos."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</aside>

.lastarticles {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-width: 25%;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-width: 285px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-width: 25%;
}
.article {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.article .thumb {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.article .thumb img {
    display: block;
}
.article .thumb:hover .hoverarticle {
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51,.7);
    opacity: 1;
}
.article .thumb:hover img {
    transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
}
.article .thumb:hover i {
    -webkit-animation: rotateInUpLeft .9s;
       -moz-animation: rotateInUpLeft .9s;
        -ms-animation: rotateInUpLeft .9s;
         -o-animation: rotateInUpLeft .9s;
            animation: rotateInUpLeft .9s;
}
.article .hoverarticle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.article .hoverarticle .readmore {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.article .hoverarticle i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20pt
}
.article .caption {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
.article .caption p {
    font-family: "open_sanslight";
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #333;
}
```

**Here's the result on Firefox (the expected one)**
[image]

**Here's the result on Chrome (weird one)**
[image]

[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvqxos7h/)

Comment: I think http://masonry.desandro.com/ can help you to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know a couple of `js´ libraries that could help me, but this looks like a chrome's fault, and I trully wanna know why this is happening @MouhamadKawas

Comment: In Chrome 41 it looks good until I hover on some of the `div`s. You 're trying to fix this on hover on Chrome, correct?

Comment: @fiskolin The problem is 
`.article .thumb:hover img.scale {
 transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
}`
This makes a bug with column in chrome on hover, only the left side works correctly. I'm not sure if scale can be resolved in this conflict on chrome.

Comment: @Nima I realized that if I add `position: relative` to `.article` the images show correctly, but the hover bugs aon the left side, even on `.thumb:hover .hoverarticle`.

Comment: @fiskolin `transition: transform` and `-webkit-column-count: 4` create conflict after the first row, it's a bug that current version of Chrome has... I think you better turn off the transform in Chrome only, or use jQuery to make that scale fade in-out effect.

Comment: @Nima yes, I really note that. In fact, I used jQuery to quit this mess. Thanks

Comment: Wow, I just found this issue two years later... and it still broken in Chrome 56!

Comment: This fix worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287243/css-3-animation-transform-scale-on-column-element-doesnt-work-on-chrome