# CSS 3 animation "transform: scale" on column element doesn't work on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

I encounter an issue in Chrome v44, I tried to zoom in on the image in item of column with a "transform: scale(1.1)", the animation doesn't work… And if I try on firefox it works well! I think the problem is due to chrome but I'd like to know if someone found a workaround.

```
    .column-wrap {
      columns: 3;
    }

    .column-item {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .column-img-wrap {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .column-img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: transform .3s ease;
    }

    .column-img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
```

here is a demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyKgyW

thanks

**EDIT**: I found a workaround: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; I add this property on image wrapper class ".column-img-wrap" and the image class ".column-img" and it works perfectly !

Comment: Why is the second `transition: transform .3s ease;` there?

Comment: for the back and forth effect

Comment: But normally that’s not necessary.

Answer (score 14):

I found a workaround: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; I add this property on image wrapper class ".column-img-wrap" and the image class ".column-img" and it works perfectly !

```
.column-img-wrap {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.column-img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**demo**: http://codepen.io/nielk/pen/gaOaVz

Comment: Great fix... it is still broken in Chrome 56 and this fixed my problem.