# Image in second and third column randomly disappear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT:** Occurs in Chrome.

I have a masonry layout with multiple columns.

**Problem**: Whenever I hover over any image in the second or third column **(stretch browser)** the image disappears for some time.

**Example**: Here's Jennifer Aniston (Woman in middle of second row disappearing on hover).

[image]

**This is how it should be:**

[image]

**JSFiddle for easy access:** https://jsfiddle.net/RohitTigga/3bvdhozc/2/

Code Below:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 92.5%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.masonry {
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-column-gap: 30px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
  column-gap: 30px;
  -moz-column-fill: initial;
  -webkit-column-fill: initial;
  column-fill: initial;
}
.masonry .brick {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.masonry .brick img {
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

  //with react
  margin: 20px 0px;

}

.masonry .brick:hover img {
  //opacity: .75;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.masonry.bordered {
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
  column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
  -moz-column-gap: 50px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
  column-gap: 50px;
}
.masonry.bordered .brick {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.masonry.gutterless {
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}
.masonry.gutterless .brick {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2em;
  }

  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 1.5em;
  }

  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

HTML Below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="FredokaOne quote">Life's too short to wear boring clothes.</h1>

    <div class="masonry">
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://images6.alphacoders.com/307/307794.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2015_41/1252321/151007-jennifer-aniston-mbm_f8d9da133d1c610e6f74da6378714832.nbcnews-fp-1200-800.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/10/11/magazine/11mag-minaj-cover/11mag-minaj-cover-facebookJumbo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2015_41/1252321/151007-jennifer-aniston-mbm_f8d9da133d1c610e6f74da6378714832.nbcnews-fp-1200-800.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/article_main_image/public/media/nicki-minaj-bb38-fea-2015-billboard-650.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://runthetrap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/chi-kanye-west-honorary-doctorate-art-institute-20150317.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://runthetrap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/chi-kanye-west-honorary-doctorate-art-institute-20150317.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://cosmouk.cdnds.net/15/38/1600x800/landscape-1442576280-ellie-goulding.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://cosmouk.cdnds.net/15/38/1600x800/landscape-1442576280-ellie-goulding.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2015_41/1252321/151007-jennifer-aniston-mbm_f8d9da133d1c610e6f74da6378714832.nbcnews-fp-1200-800.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/10/11/magazine/11mag-minaj-cover/11mag-minaj-cover-facebookJumbo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://images6.alphacoders.com/307/307794.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://runthetrap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/chi-kanye-west-honorary-doctorate-art-institute-20150317.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://cosmouk.cdnds.net/15/38/1600x800/landscape-1442576280-ellie-goulding.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/10/11/magazine/11mag-minaj-cover/11mag-minaj-cover-facebookJumbo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://www.returnofkings.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Barney-Stinson.png">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://cdn-media-1.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2014/09/ted-mosby.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="https://nancyicurtis.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/header3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/afb9c20a-a28d-42c5-a7eb-2b9e01299b71/49e9a846-49ea-4233-8db6-cb0f65041de9.png">
        </div>
        <div class="brick">
            <img src="http://legendsrevealed.com/entertainment/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/lily2.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Why is this occurring and how can this be resolved?**

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox 51.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Xufox , I will add that I got this in Chrome.

Comment: _"disappearing on hover"_ Cannot reproduce at chromium. Though there does appear to be a `css` `:hover`, `mouseover` or `mouseenter` event attached to elements where image toggles visibility for under a second, then returns to visible state.

Comment: nearly https://jsfiddle.net/3bvdhozc/10/

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're transitioning from no property to `transform: scale(1.1)`, transition [assumes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) there are two values in which define a initial state and an end state to the transition. That causes that strange flickering and disappearing of the images when the effect alternates

Check the following [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bvdhozc/9/).

But basically adding this to your  `.masonry .brick img` class, will to the trick:

```
.masonry .brick img {
  /* transition stuff */

  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1); 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:** Ok, apparently there is also a bug on chrome that using column with scaled containers makes them act as `overflow: hidden` was active and, therefore, cut the image on the limit of the wrapper that the columns are defined.

The workaround I found was *(wait for it...)* to include `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `.masonry` class as such:

```
.masonry {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* actual workaround */
    backface-visibility: hidden; /* perhaps this is not needed */
}
```

Check the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/3bvdhozc/15/) for details. *EDIT:* previous link was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help Lucas. Just a quick q, why does barney stinson, the blonde male in the grid, still flicker? It seems like that is the ONLY image that does. This is when I have 3 columns stretched.

Comment: @RohitTigga True, it's weird but apparently chrome has a problem with scaled divs wrapped around columns, I've updated the answer to reflect the fix to that problem. (ps: I guess all images on the edges were suffering from that Barney Stinson problem).

Comment: Lucas, this answer was legen....I hope Chrome isn't lactose-intolerant because the second half of that word is DAIRY.

Comment: But in all seriousness, I added -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; and it looks like Stinson totally disappeared. 

(Probably went to MacLaren's).

Comment: @RohitTigga Hahahah! Really? That's weird, btw I've actually forgot to update the fiddle on the answer, can you check if [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/3bvdhozc/15/) still has the error? Which Chrome version are you in? I'm on 53.0, but the workaround was supposed to work on Chrome 44+ [reference question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287243/css-3-animation-transform-scale-on-column-element-doesnt-work-on-chrome)

Comment: Hey Lucas, just double checked that one you just commented! It looks like does. :/ I'm fully updated on Chrome. Not sure why this is happening? :/

Comment: @RohitTigga That workaround should do the trick, are you sure Barney is disappearing or it is just appearing at the bottom of the second column due to the container width? That may be a problem with the way the columns are wrapping the content, but here when Barney disappears it is because it appeared on the bottom of the second row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124907/discussion-between-lucas-lazaro-and-rohit-tigga).

Comment: In my case i was influencing the brightness of the image trough "filter: brightness". The solution you provided in the edit helped in my situation. It seems that using any filters can also trigger this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `.brick` (parent element of the the image) and this will do the trick even with latest Chrome (7/1/2017); note: `overflow: visible;` won't work. I have the same problem and this workaround works for me, hope it will on yours.

[image]